# Loop through related section's entries

Tags: entry, sections, loop

I have two sections:
games
publishers

For example, a games entry title would be "Mario Brothers" and a publishers entry title would be "Nintendo"

On the entry page for Nintendo, I want to display all games (entries) they published.

The "_entry,html" page for publishers right now only has the following code:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block content %}
    <article>
        <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>      
        {{ entry.body }}
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

So I know I need to add it after:

```
</article>
```

In the games section, I have a field called "GamePublishers" set to type Entries. So I assign the publisher of a game via the admin cp. Wasn't sure if I need to also setup a field type entries in GamePublishers to reference to Games section. (If that makes sense)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wasn't sure if I need to also setup a field type entries in GamePublishers to reference to Games section.

Not necessary if you already have a "GamePublishers" Entry field in the "Games" section.

Something like this should work:

```
{% set games = craft.entries.section('games').relatedTo(publisher) %}
```

That's assuming you've already got a variable named `publisher` defined that's referencing the current publisher the user is viewing.

I'd suggest reading through the [relations](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations) docs as well.  Craft has a pretty powerful relations engine you can do all sorts of crazy stuff with.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work...

{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block content %}
 <article>
  <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>  
  {{ entry.body }}
 </article>
 
 {% set games = craft.entries.section('games').relatedTo(publisher) %}
 <ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a> ({{ entry.GamesReleaseYear.format('Y') }})
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
 </ul>
{% endblock %}

Comment: That's a bit hard to read, are you defining the variable `publisher` somewhere?  It should be a reference to the publisher the user is currently viewing.

Comment: Ok, I updated it. It is listing games, but it is listing ALL games and not those specific to the publisher. I'm using: {% set entries = craft.entries.section('games').relatedTo(GamesPublisher) %}

Answer (score 0):

Think I finally got it. Here is my code.

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block content %}
    <article>
        <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>      
        {{ entry.body }}
    </article>

    <h2>Games</h2>

    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('games').relatedTo(entry) %}

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries.order('title') %}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>{% if entry.GamesGenre is not empty %} ({% for category in entry.GamesGenre %}{{ category.title }}{% endfor %}){% endif %}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```